# How I clear signature pad in angular. I used two signature pads. When click clear button in second signature pad it clear first signature pad

Tags: html, angular

@ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePadStaff!: SignaturePad;
@ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePadCustomer!: SignaturePad;

i used for different signature pad like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25vNm.png)

**Signature card for Staff**

```
   <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="card signature_card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h6>Staff Signature</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="signature-container">
                <signature-pad [options]="SignaturePadOptionsStaff" (onEndEvent)="drawCompleteStaff()"
                               id="StaffSignature">
                </signature-pad>

              </div>
              <button type="button" (click)="drawClearStaff()" class="btn float-right clear_btn">Clear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Signature card for customer**

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="card signature_card">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h6>Customer Signature</h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="signature-container">
                  <signature-pad [options]="SignaturePadOptionsCustomer" (onEndEvent)="drawCompleteCustomer()"
                                 id="CustomerSignature">
                  </signature-pad>
                </div>
              <button type="button" (click)="drawClear()" class="btn float-right clear_btn">Clear</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Signature pad options**

SignaturePadOptionsCustomer: Object = {
'minWidth': 2,
'canvasWidth':   380,
'canvasHeight': 140
}
SignaturePadOptionsStaff: Object = {
'minWidth': 2,
'canvasWidth':   380,
'canvasHeight': 140
}

**Clear and Submit buttons functions**

```
 drawCompleteCustomer(){
  this.isFind = true;
  this.model.CustomerSignature = 
 this.signaturePadCustomer.toDataURL('image/png',0.5);
 }
drawCompleteStaff(){
this.isFind = true;
const base64 = this.signaturePadStaff.toDataURL('image/png',0.5);
this.model.StaffSignature =  base64
}
drawClear(){
this.signaturePadStaff.clear();
}
drawClearStaff(){
this.signaturePadStaff.clear();
}
```

**ngAfterViewInit**

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.signaturePadCustomer.set('minWidth', 2);
 this.signaturePadStaff.set('minWidth',2);
 this.signaturePadCustomer.clear();
 this.signaturePadStaff.clear();
 }
```

Comment: Show us the code, no images.

Comment: It looks like that might be expected since you're referencing the same component in both so the first one wins. If you provide a reproducible example in maybe stackblitz or something of your method it would help us help you.

Comment: pls show us your code

Comment: Give the pads different ref names and use those in the `@ViewChild` to refer to each individually, see https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#:~:text=A%20template%20reference%20variable

Comment: I Updatedmy code Please help me

Answer (score 0):

In your templates give the pads different ref names:

```html
<signature-pad #staff>...</signature-pad>
<signature-pad #customer>...</signature-pad>
```

And in your component class refer to them by those names:

```js
@ViewChild('staff') staffPad: SignaturePad;
@ViewChild('customer') customerPad: SignaturePad;
```

That is the solution for your view child problem.

To implement clearing, I would pass the actual pad to the `drawClear` method like this:

```html
<button (click)="drawClean(staff)">...</button> <!-- for staff -->
...
<button (click)="drawClean(customer)">...</button> <!-- for customer -->
```

And in your component class, modify `drawClear` to use this argument:

```js
drawClear(pad: SignaturePad){
  pad.clear();
}
```